# Why this *ngIf not render my paragraph checking the value of a variable?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

I am working on an Angular application and I am finding the following problem using *ngIf directive.

Into my HTML code I have put:

```
<p>{{selectedAssetType}}</p>
<p *ngIf="selectedAssetType === 'NB'">TEST</p>
```

As you can see first I am printing the **selectedAssetType** variable value via interpolation. Then if the value of this variable is **NB** I want to print the TEST paragraph.

This is what I am obtaining:

[image]

As you can see the value of the **selectedAssetType** printed is **NB** but then the **ngIf** is not working because no TEST paragraph is rendered.

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: did you try comparing with == operator?

Comment: @tmsbrndz yes...same result

Comment: can you make some stackblitz or something? Or you can post your ts also.

Comment: Can you `console.log` the value of `selectedAssetType` adding any symbol at the front and end of the value, might be due to the extra spacing on the `NB` value? As from what I can see the code seems good. Or having stackblitz sample like what @tmsbrndz suggested will be easier for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

First try replacing that logic with a `true` value. That way you will find if the problem is the equality verification or the actual directive and how it is used. As far as I can see the problem is probably coming from the selectedAssetType. You might have whitespaces after `NB` or maybe it is not a string, it might be an object, especially if you are working with enums. Try trimming it and casting it to a string. If you have enums you can also give each key a certain value like: NB = 'NB'.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to write more code in the TS as in the HTML for *ngIf.
For example.

```
public checkNB() {
return this.selectedAssetType === "NB";
}
```

Then in your HTML you can write only.

```
*ngIf="checkNB
```

Comment: It still not work. It seems to me that ngIf is not "recognized" in the HTML of this specific component. For example I also tried <p *ngIf= "1 === 1">TEST</p> or <p *ngIf=true>TEST</p> and it is not working

Comment: did you add Common module to NgModules? Please check console errors..

Comment: @AndreaNobili Can you share with us your `app.module.ts`, because as @tmsbrndz said maybe you are forgeting to import some modules which will doesn't recognise `'ngIf`.